# Git and crontab

Tags: linux, git, cron

How do I run `git pull` command using crontab? When I run it manually from the directory it works, however when I add the command as a `crontab` job it does not work.

The command in crontab file looks like this:

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/repo/.git && git pull
```

I will not push anything from this machine, just need a local copy to be synced with main repository.

The ERROR I am getting is:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Comment: You are "jumping" into the wrong directory, if `/path/to/repo/` is your git working tree, just `cd /path/to/repo` and not `cd /path/to/repo.git`. Anyway, this is not a programming question, I think it is out of the scope of SO.

Comment: yea thanks. I made a dumb mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend pulling with crontab as it can be extremely unefficient, also with git pulling every 1 minute you can run into many problems.

See this script, it might help you:

https://github.com/olipo186/Git-Auto-Deploy

This way pull will be only triggered on each push.

If you still wish to go with crontab try - it should work like this:

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/repo && git pull
```

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: thanks. I need it to run once a day actually. So crontab should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/repo/ && git pull
```

You don't need to go in to the `.git` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
* * * * * git -C /path/to/repo pull
```

From the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt):

> **`-C <path>`**
>   Run as if git was started in `<path>` instead of the current working directory.